# echo utf-8 text when scraping a web page

Tags: php, utf-8, web-scraping

im scraping a specific data from a website using this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

    <title>scrap</title>
  </head>
  <body>
<?php
$url = 'http://xn--mgbaam1d9c.com';
$html = file_get_contents( $url);

libxml_use_internal_errors( true);
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML( $html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath( $doc);

// A name attribute on a <div>???
$node = $xpath->query( '//div[@class="list"]')->item( 0);

echo $node->textContent; 

?>

</body>
</html>
```

scraping in working very good BUT

1. the result show only 1 result, i want it to show all results (The website has pagination).
2. the result in Arabic language and it shows up like this image below
   -https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9VMn.png

**so how do i make it get all results & display them in arabic language like they are.**

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You are only getting the first item `.item(0)`. Take a look at what
   `$xpath->query` returns: [`DOMNodeList`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php) which has a `length`
   property.
2. Convert the encoding from `windows-1256` to `utf-8` using
   [`iconv`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php).

Something like this:

```
$nodeList = $xpath->query( '//div[@class="list"]');

for ( $i = 0; $i < $nodeList->length; $i++ ) {
    $node = $nodeList->item($i);
    echo iconv('WINDOWS-1256','UTF-8',$node->textContent);
}
```

*Edit:* [`mb_convert_encoding`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) doesn't support windows-1256, switched to [`iconv`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) instead.

---

You could also dynamically retrieve the content encoding from the HTML meta:

```
$fromEncoding = '';
$contentType = $xpath->query('//meta[@http-equiv="content-type"]')->item(0)->getAttribute('content');
preg_match('/charset=([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$/',$contentType,$contentTypeMatches);
if ( isset($contentTypeMatches[1]) ) {
    $fromEncoding = strtoupper($contentTypeMatches[1]);
}
```